# Choosing between custom JPanel and JTable layout

Tags: java, jpanel

I'm trying to set up a JPanel which will display lines and text horizontally. It will take a text file, and I'm trying to display the lines and text at the same time given the size of the file. Would it be more appropriate (being relatively new to coding) to use a JTable layout, or make my own layout on a JPanel?

Comment: Do you mean you want to display the file contents in something like a JFrame?

Comment: yeah, it's currently on a JFrame

Comment: Have you considered using a JTextArea/JTextPane to display your text file contents?

Comment: no, but I will give it a go now. Are there any benefits or reasons why I should?

Comment: JTextArea is just plain text that you can format with line breaks. Main advantage: it's simple. And that's probably a good start for a beginner.

Comment: what about custom fonts and straight lines?

Comment: What are you getting at when you say "Straight lines"?

Comment: putting strings on the lines like.... -----string---- or similar to a strikethrough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a very basic example on how you could use a JTextPane to display some text from a text file within a JFrame.  If you want to do anything more then things like layoutmangers will come into play, but for simple text display this should be suitable:

```
public class SO{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
    frame.add(pane);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\Users\\user2777005\\Desktop\\test.txt"));
    String everything = "";
    try {
        StringBuilder sbuild = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                sbuild.append(line);
                sbuild.append('\n');
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            everything = sbuild.toString();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
    pane.setFont(new Font("Segoe Print", Font.BOLD, 12));
    pane.setText(everything);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

As shown a JTexPane does also allow for Font changes.

Good luck!

Comment: And a HTMLEditorKit could add straight lines. But i think that's a bit excessive.

Comment: ah man, thanks for the advice, but I'm going to brave it and make it with a JPanel!